# How can I 2 global variables with the same name in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've 2 global variables came from 2 different third-party files , the 2 variables have the same name.
I used to use it like :

```
declare var someVar;
```

But what if I want to use the 2 variables ?

```
declare var someVar;
declare var someVar;
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Declare them in separate classes?

Comment: You can not under the same class. that's the basic rule :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have variables having same name in the same scope. Consider if it was possible then how would the compiler determine which one you meant. So, It's not possible.

Comment: I thought that there is a way to set the source of that variable then put an alias & path beside it .